# how to check if row exist with trigger in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, validation, triggers

I want to check if a row exist with a trigger before insert here is my table and my trigger

Table students: ID | Name

Trigger validation :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `validation` BEFORE INSERT ON `students` 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin

declare var_name varchar(255);
declare check_row varchar(255);

set var_name = new.name;
select name into check_row from students where name = var_name;

end
```

Comment: Why use a trigger and not the `on duplicate key` syntax?

Comment: Yes but i want to see how to make it with trigger ..

Comment: If a row is found, what do you want to do? Ignore it?

Comment: i want to check if there is a row if yes set new.name = 'wrroong'

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a stored procedure, you can accomplish this with a handler if the column has a unique key on it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `student_create` (IN name_in VARCHAR(64), ...)
BEGIN

  SET @name = name_in;

  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000'
    SET @name = CONCAT('dupe_',name_in);

  INSERT INTO students (name, ...) VALUES (@name, ...);

END$$
```

If you are really set on using a trigger, all you need is an if

```
IF (SELECT id FROM students WHERE name = NEW.name) THEN
  SET var_name = CONCAT('dupe_',NEW.name);
END IF;
```

Replace the CONCAT with whatever transformation you want perform on the `name`